# How to create a detailed report from SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query which looks like this:

```
SELECT 
a.Name as 'Name of the program',
a.ContractCode as Code,
case 
when a.IsActive = 1 THEN 'YES'
when a.IsActive = 0 THEN 'NO'
end as ACTIVE,
a.StartDate as 'Contract  Start Date',
a.EndDate as 'Contract  End Date',
case 
when a.Description IS NULL THEN ''
else a.Description 
End as 'Description',
b.Name as 'Service provider’s name',
a.CountryISO2 as 'Country',
c.DisplayName as 'Default Language'

FROM [Config].[Contract] a
join [dbo].[ServiceProvider] b on a.ServiceProviderID = b.ServiceProviderID
join [Config].[Languages] c on a.LanguageId = c.Id
```

I need to convert every row into a detailed report which will look like below:

FROM:

```
Name Program|Code|ACTIVE|Contract  Start Date|Contract  End Date |Description|Service provider’s name|Country |Default Language
```

TO:

```
Name Program: 
Code:
ACTIVE:
Contract  Start Date:
Contract  End Date:
Description:
Service provider’s name:
Country:
Default Language:
```

How can I convert it in SQL/T-SQL?

Comment: What do you mean a detailed report?  Something in SQL Server Reporting Services?  An email of the text you described?  A web page that you're writing that reads from your database?  Something else?  Expand on what you need as much as possible :)

Comment: You mean you want to display the columns vertically, and then vertically again for the next record? SQL is not designed for presentational work. Rather you would use another tool. SQL Server has a Reporting Services feature, or you could use some other report-building tool (there are many on the market) or make a custom application to present your data (e.g. in a web page or Excel sheet or PDF or something). The client application (SSRS, custom app, or other tool like Crystal Reports) would run the SQL query, get the results and then format it into the desired presentation style.

Comment: @MatBailie it can be csv/text file even. I just need a report from up to down - not in columns

Comment: @KacperG your desired output is not suited for CSV, which is designed for tabular data in rows/columns (much like the standard output of a SQL query) in order to transmit data in a machine-readable format. Your desired format looks like it's designed to be human-readable instead. A plain text file would be more plausible, but whatever you do, you can't do it with just SQL. As I mentioned you need some external code.

Comment: It seems like you're simply asking how to extract the tabular data resulting from your SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

If you want this as a single string, just concatenate everything, with newlines in between?

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    'Name of the program : ', a.name, CHAR(13), CHAR(10),
    'Code : ', a.ContractCode, CHAR(13), CHAR(10),
    'Active : ', case a.IsActive when 1 THEN 'YES' when 0 then 'NO' end, CHAR(13), CHAR(10),
    etc, etc
  )
    AS report_string
FROM [Config].[Contract] a
join [dbo].[ServiceProvider] b on a.ServiceProviderID = b.ServiceProviderID
join [Config].[Languages] c on a.LanguageId = c.Id
```

Comment: Ummm, then just ensure everything is a string type *(using `CAST()`)* and then concatenate everything with `+`?